# Is this a "locally surjective" function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I quote the "locally surjective" part because I haven't found any reference of that concept, but it kind of fits what I mean.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^M, f \in C^1, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N : rank(Df(x_0)) = M$. Show that $\exists U \subset \mathbb{R}^M$ neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$ such that $U \subset Im(f)$.

I'm struggling to get an intuition of why should this happen, but haven't made any progress. Could any of you please provide me some hints about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know what is a submersion ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)#Local_normal_form ... read this...you'll get your ans

Comment: Erh, not actually -- but I do now. Thanks for your answer @Anubhav.K, and excuse me for my ignorance (never studied manifolds). One last question: does $f$ have to be $C^1$? By what I've read I think it'd be sufficient for $f$ to be differentiable.